# EditText contents validation

Tags: android, android-edittext

I was validating my `EditText` contents,

I used validating my `EditText` contents using

```
String enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
String enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();

if( enteredUserName != " " && enteredPassword != " " ) {
    createNewAccount();
}
```

but above did't work for me, 
then i see a solution of this,

```
if( enteredUserName.length() != 0 && enteredPassword.length() != 0 ) {
    createNewAccount();
}
```

It worked perfectly for me

My question is, why my first code snippet not worked, while i have used above code for validation in java.
Thanks

**Edit2**

```
setContentView( R.layout.create_account_activity_layout );
btn = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.create_account_btn );
userName = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.name );
userPassword = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.password );

enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

userName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               if( enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0){
                   createNewAccount();
               }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

userPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {     
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if( enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0){
               createNewAccount();
           }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
});
```

**Edit3**

```
String enteredUserName; 
String enteredPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    setContentView( R.layout.create_account_activity_layout );
    btn = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.create_account_btn );
    userName = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.name );
    userPassword = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.password );

    enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
    enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    userName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
                enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();
                 if( enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0){
                       createNewAccount();
                 }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    userPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {         
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
             enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();
             if( enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0){
                   createNewAccount();
               }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    /*while( enteredUserName.toString().isEmpty() || enteredPassword.toString().isEmpty() ) {
        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Please enter proper user name and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        userName = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.name );
        userPassword = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.password );
        enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim(); 
        enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    }*/
    /*  while( userName.getText().toString().equals("")  && userPassword.getText().toString().equals("") ) {
        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Please enter proper user name and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
    }*/
    btn.setOnClickListener( this );
}
```

**Edit4**

```
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    setContentView( R.layout.create_account_activity_layout );
    btn = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.create_account_btn );
    userName = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.name );
    userPassword = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.password );

    //enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
    //enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
            String enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();
            if (enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
    userName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    userPassword.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    /*
    userName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

             enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
             enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();
             if( enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0){
                   createNewAccount();
             }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    userPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
             enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();
             if( enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0){
                   createNewAccount();
               }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    */
    /*while( enteredUserName.toString().isEmpty() || enteredPassword.toString().isEmpty() ) {
        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Please enter proper user name and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        userName = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.name );
        userPassword = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.password );
        enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim(); 
        enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    }*/
    /*  while( userName.getText().toString().equals("")  && userPassword.getText().toString().equals("") ) {
        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Please enter proper user name and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }*/
    btn.setOnClickListener( this );
}
```

Comment: You're only checking for a space: " " in your first code, not an empty character, so if you change it to "" without the space in the middle, it should work.

Comment: Empty string doesn't store as " ". It stores as "".

Comment: @jyoon you are perfect

Comment: Another way ...use isempty() method  & use String Trim

Comment: @Programmer Do you try my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first solution didn't work because you try to compare instance of your text with instance of String which contains only one space.

The second solution will work, but if user will write space the condition will be validated, so you should `trim()` your string before you check the condition as is shown in code below:

```
if( enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0){
     createNewAccount();
}
```

the `trim()` method remove white marks from your `String`

Or you can use method `isEmpty()` from String class

If you want to recognise situation where user change text on `EditText` you should use `TextWatcher` as is shown in code below:

```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               String enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
               String enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();
               if( enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0){
                   createNewAccount();
               }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Add TextWatcher as I shown for `userName` and `userPassword`

**EDIT**

Change your onCreate method to the method below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_account_activity_layout);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById( R.id.create_account_btn );
    final EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    userName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    userPassword.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
            String enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();
            if (enteredUserName.trim().length() != 0 && enteredPassword.trim().length() != 0) {
                createNewAccount();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Fill both fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare Strings You have to do it like this:

```
  if( !enteredUserName.equals(" ") && !enteredPassword.equals(" ") ) {
      createNewAccount();
 }
```

For comparing Strings allways use the method equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() if the capital letters are not important

Comment: yes yes i also tried 

      if( userName.getText().toString().equals(" ")  &&   userPassword.getText().toString().equals(" ") )

but it too did't work

Comment: because you're looking for a space - that won't be in the edittext unless you enter it as username and password. you should trim and check if it is empty or not afterwards

Comment: actually i was checking either a user enters something in edittext or not, if he enters something then move to next activity

Answer (score 0):

You did String comparision by = which is not possible - just use

```
if(!enteredUserName.equals("") && !enteredPassword.equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
     String enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();

     if( !enteredUserName.equals("") && !enteredPassword.equals("") ) {
          createNewAccount();
     }
```

In addition

Read this document http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Other solution

```
String enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
         String enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();

         if( !enteredUserName.isEmpty() && !enteredPassword.isEmpty() ) {
              createNewAccount();
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare strings with !=, it's not good idea you can compare it with :

-`if(enteredUserName.equals("") && enteredPassword.equals(""))`

-`if(enteredUserName.toString().isEmpty() && enteredPassword.toString().isEmpty()`

-`if(enteredUserName.matches("") && enteredPassword.matches("")`

There are a lot of posibilities to compare it, but those are the most correct IMO.

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT**

If you want to use length one way to use it would be like :

```
if (enteredUserName.getText().length() == 0) && (enteredPassword.getText().length() == 0)
```

**EDIT2**

Try this logic and let me know if it works.

```
 String enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString();
 String enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString();

 Boolean ok;
 ok = false;
 while (!ok) {
    if (!enteredUserName.equals("") && !enteredPassword.equals("")){
        ok = true;
        createNewAccount();
        //user and password are not empty or you can do your 
    }
    else {
        //do something to repeat this, because user or password is empty
    }
 }
```

Comment: length of String is not important for me, i just want to validate on runtime that either a user enters something in edit text or just move further

Comment: @Programmer Try the other solutions that I gave to you :)

Comment: when i use this code, 
          while( enteredUserName.toString().isEmpty() ||    enteredPassword.toString().isEmpty() ) {
Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Please enter proper user name and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   userName = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.name );
   userPassword = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.password );
  }


control goes to infinity loop and activity does't displayed

Comment: its ok for me, but for someone's else may be headache :)

Comment: @Programmer I know I know... my bad, did you try my logic?

Comment: i think i should use textChangeListener

Comment: @Programmer try my edit2 again, let me see if with equals it works, if it doesn't work paste your Log cat error to see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String enteredUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
 String enteredPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

 if( !enteredUserName.equalsIgnoreCase("")
      && !enteredPassword.equalsIgnoreCase("") )
 {
      createNewAccount();
 }
```

Comment: want to use in a loop

Comment: explains better I'm not understanding your question

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
   if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty("enteredUserName")) {
     // createNewAccount();
    }
```